# android application throws host unresolved exception?

Tags: android

i have made an android application in which i am supposed to request an xml first and then parse it.
i am encountering a strange problem... sometimes when i run the application, it runs fine but others times my web request shows host unresolved exception on port 80. i don't understand why this is happening. 
when the exception is being thrown, if i try to access the url via web browser, it opens up fine. So there is no problem server side.

what could be going wrong?

thank you in advance.

edit: when i restarted the emulator the anomaly got solved.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your network connection is flakey

Answer (score 0):

The network connection of your phone (or the virtual device) is probably buggy. You should try to catch the exception and display an error message and/or retry the request a couple seconds later.

Answer (score 0):

You can try dumping the traffic with tcpdump (http://www.vbsteven.be/blog/android-debugging-inspectin-network-traffic-with-tcpdump/) to see if there is something wrong with the connnection.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem on the emulator. Try a restart.